# influxdb query with multiple count aggregate and corresponding where clauses

Tags: influxdb

I have a table in influxdb with the following format

[image]

With values 0,1,2 correlating to norun, pass, and fail.
Is it possible to run a single query that will return a result set of the distinct count of the value, grouped by the id?

For example, I want the output:

[image]

So essentially, the results from

```
SELECT COUNT(value) FROM <table> WHERE value = 0 GROUP BY id
SELECT COUNT(value) FROM <table> WHERE value = 1 GROUP BY id
SELECT COUNT(value) FROM <table> WHERE value = 2 GROUP BY id
```

...but within a single query that I can map to a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Group by](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-tags) clause only supports tags from your measurement.  `Show tag Keys` [command](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/schema_exploration/#show-tag-keys) list out all tags from your measurement. If `value` in your measurement is a tag, you can rewrite your query as follows to attain what you are looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(value) FROM <table> group by id, value;
```